# How to reset a PostgreSQL database to its previous state during a Rails 4 migration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec

I'm testing migrations in a Rails 4.2.x application with Postgres 9.3, and came up with the following which seems to work.  I added a migration "AddCarIdToWheels" to the test database and ran it using the now deprecated `rake db:test:prepare`.

In the `context up` section, instead of `AddCarIdToWheels.down`, I would like to do something like `ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate @previous_version` in order to reset the database to its previous state before the `car_id` column was added to the Wheels table.  But if I do that instead of `AddCarIdToWheels.down` I get a "column already exists" error in the Postgres test database.

How do I write the "context up" rspec test so it's not dependent on the state of the database, i.e. `car_id` column has already been added?

Is it possible to do it without dropping the test database? If I delete the table, I think I'm going to have to manually recreate the username and password to access the test database from the command line every single test run, which is too time consuming.

I used "[Start Testing Your Migrations. (Right Now)](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/01/27/start-testing-your-migrations-right-now/)" as a guide.

spec/add_car_id_to_wheels_spec.rb:

```
    require 'spec_helper'
    require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "..", "..", "db", "migrate", "20150609194738_add_car_id_to_wheels")

    RSpec.describe "AddCarIdToWheels" do

      before do
        @current_version = '20150609194738'
        @previous_version = '20150528183542'
      end

      context "up" do
        before do
          AddCarIdToWheels.down
          puts "Testing up migration for #{@current_version} - resetting to #{@previous_version}"
        end

        it "adds the car_id column to the wheels table", :please_truncate=>true do
          expect {
            AddCarIdToWheels.up
            Wheel.reset_column_information
          }.to change { Wheel.columns }
          expect(Wheel.column_names).to include("car_id")
        end
      end

      context "down" do
        before do
          ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate @current_version
          puts "Testing down migration for #{@current_version} - resetting to #{ActiveRecord::Migrator.current_version}"
        end

        it "removes the car_id column to the wheels table" do
          expect {
            AddCarIdToWheels.down
            Wheel.reset_column_information
          }.to change { Wheel.columns }
          expect(Wheel.column_names).not_to include("car_id")
        end
      end

  end
```

Comment: Your test database should be cleaned before your test suite runs.  If there is stuff in it you need for testing, then you should but that in a before(:suite) block.

Comment: In this case the test setup needs to not just delete the rows of data, but to actually remove a whole column.

Comment: Can you use `rake db:migrate` and `rake db:rollback` if the migration did not fail?